# Windows Server 2012 - Can't join computer to the domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

This was supposed to be an easy one but I ran into an issue here.

I set up the domain and a static IP on the server. The server is connected to a router/AP (which obviously functions as a switch) as well as the client, both are hardwired.

When I try to join the computer via This PC, I get prompted to enter the credentials and then I received the following error: "The following domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

When I go to a different computer and try to log into the domain from the logon screen.

I receive the following error: "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship".

I haven't been able to join a single computer to the domain, what am I missing here?

Don't ask me to rejoin the computer to the domain because I haven't been able to join anything at all

Answer (score 8):

This is almost certainly a DNS issue. Make sure that your clients are configured to use a resolver that is able to resolve queries for your AD domain.

Comment: Agreed. This most definitely sounds like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1):

You said the server has a static IP address, but you didn't mention the PC. Most APs have DHCP running. If that's where the PC got it's address, then you need to either enter your domain controller as the DNS server that your AP gives out, or manually override the DNS server used by the PC when it gets an address from the AP.

Answer (score 0):

as all the others have said.

1. make sure pc is on same network as server with the server address as the DNS server for the pc.

assuming tis was the first Dc in which case it is a DNS server too.

To join a domain the pc needs to find the srv records for the domain, Kerberos and ldap specifically.

2. DHCP server make sure it is issuing the right ip address gateway and dns server.
3. before join run ipconfig /flushdns

4 final check the HOSTS file on the pc in case someone is having some fun with you and has hardwired a dns entry in....

if it can see the server and the server is healthy then a domain join will result.

final option is to do an offline domain join.

as shown here

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step(v=ws.10).aspx

good luck, and don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped and vote helpful in any case

cheers

ed

Answer (score 0):

Id set the IP of the client to an address on the same subnet which isnt being used. Also set the DNS of the client to point to the DC.
Make sure DNS is running on your DC.
Now try and join the PC.

As others are saying, your client is probably picking up an address and DNS settings from your SOHO Router/Switch and it has not name entries for your DC.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which involved static IP's. I did the following:

1. I disabled IPV6 temporarily because when pinged using the FQDN it returned "ping request could not fined host...".
2. Changed the DNS to point to the domain controller

After these two steps I was able to ping the DC using the FQDN successfully and was able to join the domain.

Answer (score 0):

ISP DNS is being query'd and not your DNS server regardless if you input your static IP in preferred DNS in TCP settings.I wrestled with this for a few days before being able to piece together various info on the net. I have built small networks before and this problem had me stumped. The only difference was this network was at home lab. Made sense that it did not work with my Uverse because the options are so limited on my modem. Not sure if you have to contact your ISP Host to make changes, but I just created a host only environment, cutting out the access to the internet and any need to query ISP DNS and the clients connect without a problem. This solved my issue but you may have the need to connect to the internet. If your ISP can not make adjustments, possibly bridge a VM router or use Windows DHCP server to pass traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell what happened to me!

In my case i just installed a "Windows Server 2008 R2" to be the Active Directory and I added only the AD role.
I was receiving the same error message ("*The following domain either does not exist or could not be contacted*") while joining a new computer to the just created domain, which presented no problem during the creation.

In resume, my problem was that I did not add the DNS role together AD role in the "Windows Server 2008 R2". After add the DNS role and include a new computer in the AD group, it worked like a charm, so you will need at least both roles to have your AD properly working.

Also, this advice to point your AD as the DNS for the machine that you are trying to join is interesting: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/254661-help-cannot-join-computer-back-to-domain-on-windows-7

Check it!

Cheers